# The page at localhost says Error: [object Object] while getting data from database using ajax

Tags: php, json, ajax

When i run this code i am having this problem "The page at localhost  says Error: [object Object]" and nothing shows in console log. When i run the php code and var_dump($json). The code run with no error and all data shows on the screen as i expected.

```
      $.ajax({
        url: 'post.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        beforeSend: function() {
            // console.log('Request sending for data.');
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },  
        error: function (error){
            alert("Error: " + error);
        }
    });
```

This is my php Code with no error when i run it like "localhost/learn/post.php" and it show all the data that is in the database using var_dump($json).

```
 $dbcon = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "blog");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM posts";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $json[] = $row;
    };

    echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: Check you browser console for error

Comment: can you please describe scenario in detail?

Comment: You can't echo an array you need print_r(json_encode($json)). This is why you are getting console logs while using var_dump and nothing while using echo

Comment: @Saty i checked it and there is no error in console.

Comment: @AmitSingh i tried but still getting the same error.

Comment: @PRANAV i want to get the query result in the form of object on my webpage.

Comment: can you put `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));` in your AJAX success call and edit your code with the error recieved.. ?

Comment: @Chandan "" are printed in console.

Comment: @Zeeshan means you want to get the result as a object? instead of json?

Comment: @PRANAV yes. About 5 months ago i used ajax at that time i get the object with the same scenario but now i am getting error.

Comment: so can replace all $_POST and$_GET with $_REQUEST using this it will get all the data whether ajax call method is post or get...

Comment: @PRANAV don't understand your point.

Comment: in your all php page code wherever you use like $_POST['keyname'] or $)GET['keyName'] replace and use $_REQUEST['keyname']

Comment: I'm not usig any $_GET or $_POST in my php code. I just want to grab all the data that is in the posts table. I'm not comparing anything.

Comment: seems to be an issue with the `json_encode()` .. do the following in PHP code - `$jsonData = json_encode($json);  echo json_last_error() ` this is to test what error you are getting..

Comment: @Chandan 5 is printed in the console.

Comment: that means issue with the JSON data ... `JSON_ERROR_UTF8 Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded` check your `$json` variable.. if  it contains some characters or formats which can not be  converted to JSON

Comment: @Chandan Thanks man got it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
      $.ajax({
    url: 'post.php',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
        var result = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(result);
    },  
});
```

Comment: Getting this error in console when i run the code as you asked "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input".

Comment: im forget to remove comma
$.ajax({
    url: 'post.php',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
        var result = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(result);
    }
});

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Comment: thats error means that has error on the syntax(maybe mistype or you forgot something on your code), im trying to run this code in my console and not getting that error.